# iOS13 - UISearchController with modalPresentationStyle popover ignores the notch safe area

Tags: ios, swift

As the question suggest, I am trying to show a `UISearchController` with `modalPresentationStyle` equal to `.popover`.
With every phone this works fine, but, in models that have a notch (like the iPhone 11 pro) the notch covers my search bar.
Also, I had to hide the status bar, otherwise it would overlap my search bar.
Here is the Swift code I am using to setup the search controller where `locationSearchTable` is a `UITableViewController`:

```
            controller = UISearchController(searchResultsController: locationSearchTable)
            controller.searchResultsUpdater = locationSearchTable
            let searchBar = controller.searchBar
            searchBar.sizeToFit()
            searchBar.placeholder = "Search for places"
            
            parent.mapView.addSubview(controller.searchBar)
            
            controller.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
            controller.modalTransitionStyle = .coverVertical
            controller.modalPresentationCapturesStatusBarAppearance = true
            controller.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = true
```

I have tried many things, most of them being attempting to use insets and changing the origin of the search bar to lower it a bit. Adding insets did nothing (unless I added negative insets, in that case the search bar went up, but of course this is not what I wanted) and changing the origin of the frame (`searchBar.frame.origin.y += 10`) would send the search bar below the `tableView`, hiding it instead of moving it down.

Is there a way to add a margin or simply make it so that the search view respects the top safe area?

Here is what I get right now:
[image: Notch covering search bar]

You can also see that there is an empty space after the search bar and before having the first row of the result list. It may be that the two problems are related, but I am not entirely sure.

Comment: I would guess either you need a different presentation style. Or that you should add searchBar and not controller.searchbar to the view.

Comment: We actually would like that type of presentation style (also because similar others like .fullscreen are not supported by the UISearchController) and controller.searchbar and searchbar are the same object

Comment: Any updates as to how you tackle this issue? I currently stumble with this same question on iPad. The search bar looks fine initially. But when we focus on it, it resized to the width of the popover (including the width of the protruding arrow), clipping/hiding the right part of the Cancel button.